# powershell - rename csv file based on a column value

Tags: powershell, csv, rename

My CSV file has contents like this:

```
currentTime, SeqNum, Address
1381868225469, 0, 
1381868226491, 1, 38:1c:4a:0:8d:d 
1381868227493, 1, 
1381868228513, 2, 38:1c:4a:0:8d:d 
1381868312825, 43, 
1381868312916, 1694564736, 3a:1c:4a:1:a1:98 
1381868312920, 1694564736, 3a:1c:4a:1:a1:98 
1381868312921, 44,
```

Depending on whether the 3rd column is empty or not, I want to separate the file into 2 or more files (those with lines containing the 3rd column (fileName should contain the 3rd column) and one without the 3rd column.

Example output:

```
**File0.txt**
1381868225469, 0, 
1381868227493, 1, 
1381868312825, 43, 
1381868312921, 44, 

**File1-381c4a08dd.txt**
1381868226491, 1, 38:1c:4a:0:8d:d 
1381868228513, 2, 38:1c:4a:0:8d:d 

**File2-3a1c4a1a198.txt**
1381868312916, 1694564736, 3a:1c:4a:1:a1:98 
1381868312920, 1694564736, 3a:1c:4a:1:a1:98
```

I referred to the stackoverflow questions [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413805/split-csv-file-according-to-matching-columns) and [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13619494/split-csv-file-by-columns-using-powershell) to get most of my work done. However, I want to rename my file based on the 3rd column. Since, windows does not accept ":" in the file name, I want to remove the ":" before attaching the 3rd column to my file name. I want my file name to look like this:

FileName-381c4a08dd.txt

How do I go about this? This is my attempt at it so far:

```
import-csv File.txt | group-object Address | foreach-object {
$_.group | select-object currentTime, SeqNum, Address | convertto-csv -NoTypeInformation | %{$_ -replace '"', ""} | out-file File-$($_.Address.remove(':')).txt -fo -en ascii
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$csv = Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\file.txt'
$n = 0

# export rows w/o address
$outfile = 'File${n}.txt'
$csv | ? { $null, '' -contains $_.Address } |
  Export-Csv $outfile -NoTypeInformation

# export rows w/ address
$csv | ? { $null, '' -notcontains $_.Address } | Group-Object Address | % {
  $n++
  $outfile = "File${n}-" + $_.Name.Replace(':', '') + '.txt'
  $_.Group | Export-Csv $outfile -NoTypeInformation
}
```

The filter `$null, '' -contains $_.Address` is required, because the address record will be `$null` when you have an empty address and no trailing line break in the last line of the input file.

If you want the output files to be created without header line you need to replace

```
... | Export-Csv $outfile -NoTypeInformation
```

with

```
... | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | select -Skip 1 | Out-File $outfile
```

Comment: I apologize, I wasn't clear. I have added a sample output to my question. The other rows in the file have to be written to another file. So, there has to be these files: (1). File without 3rd column (2). Files with 3rd column, however, 3rd column to be attached to filename. Hope this is clear.

Comment: @Sarvavyapi Yes, thank you for clarifying. Basically you need a combination of my previous suggestions for this. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. This works great. But there are "" in the output. I tried removing it like this: $csv | ? { $null, '' -notcontains $_.Address } | convertto-csv -NoTypeInformation | %{$_ -replace '"', ""} | Group-Object Address | % {
  $n++
  $outfile = "File_${n}-" + $_.Name.Replace(':', '') + '.txt'
  $_.Group | out-file $outfile -fo -en ascii
  #Export-Csv $outfile -NoTypeInformation
}

Comment: I figured it out. $csv | ? { $null, '' -notcontains $_.Address } | Group-Object Address | % {
  $n++
  $outfile = "File_${n}-" + $_.Name.Replace(':', '') + '.txt'
  $_.Group | convertto-csv -NoTypeInformation | %{$_ -replace '"', ""} | out-file $outfile -fo -en ascii }